# Is focusing problems on Sigma lenses still a problem on a Canon body?

Tags: lens, canon, autofocus, sigma

I am considering purchasing the Sigma 70-200mm f/2.8 EX DG HSM II Macro Lens. The problem is that many reviews point out that the lens has front focus problems, at least on a Canon mount. But those reviews date back to 2008, so things could have changed.

I have also been told that newer Sigma lenses (2010 and later) should have dealt with their focus problems.

Is that so? Can I purchase the lens and trust it to focus correctly? I have the 500D which does not have micro-focus adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOME Sigma (and indeed all 3rd party) lenses have problems on SOME Canon bodies. IF the lens is under warranty when this happens, afaik Sigma will fix the problem (which has to do with Canon's constant changes of their AF logic body/lens interface, requiring Sigma to change their chipset with nearly every new body Canon releases. It's a subtle trick by Canon to push people into buying Canon lenses...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with the 70-200 f2.8 II, but I did use the Sigma 18-125 on vacation in November with horrible results. I have the 60D and the front focusing problem with the Sigma lens was so bad that I had to stop using it.

I'm not sure it would be a problem on the older 500, or with 70-200, but it might be worth trying the lens in the shop before you pay.

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate lens I have is a Sigma 18-50mm 2.8-4 OS HSM.

My Canon lenses tend to back-focus (28mm 1.8 USM, 28-135mm IS USM, 70-300mm 4.5-5.6). And this is true on three separate bodies (400D, 450D, 40D). But I mostly do manual focus - or exploit the full-time manual override (which the sigma doesn't have, so I guess it is lucky that its focus is spot on).